# Redis Get vs Set operations performance

Tags: redis

While perusing the redis docs I stumbled upon a thing that troubled me. I read that without pipelining Set operations have more throughput than Get operations and this is strange. I read this post [Why is Redis SET performance better than GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600908/why-is-redis-set-performance-better-than-get) and I understood that with pipelining we get more throughput with Get operations rather than Set operations because we measure more correctly the performance. But without using pipelining how is it possible, even though we are measuring I/O to have more throughput in Set operation? Aren't Get operations supposed to take less cpu cycles to be executed than Set operations?